# how to initialize ProgressDialog in custom adapter

Tags: android

I am trying to use AsuncTask in custom adapter. when i tried to use

```
class UpdateProductVariantTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    String result = "";

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait.....");
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
                UpdateProductVariantTask.this.cancel(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

in line progressDialog.show();

How to fix this error?

Comment: When cancellable is false how you can catch event for cancel listener??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use Activity not context.

```
private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
```